# Strikethrough text in a code sample

Tags: support, markdown

How can I strikethrough code in a Code Sample. I would like to acheive this <del>Console.WriteLine("Strikethrough");</del>

```
// A Hello World! program in C#.
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); 
            Console.WriteLine("Strikethrough");   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the bold code question. The bold code question is asking about bolding code and this question is about striking through code.